# How to customize code coverage summary in TFS 2015

Tags: testing, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 vNext Build to manage our CI build.

It is quite easy to enable the test coverage in the visual studio test task.

But in the build summary, it only give a overall block overage percentage.

For each assembly, the summary only indicate the covered block and line.

For example:
[image]

It is quite time consuming to download and open the **.coverage file** to get the detail block covered percentage for each assembly when assembly count is huge.

Is there any way that we can configure the summary to show the block covered percentage for each assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, these customizations are not supported. You can't edit the displays in vNext build result summary.

> You can submit a feature request to User Voice site at:
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services The TFS
>   Administrator and PM will kindly review the suggestion.